# VB.NET Pass Data Between Forms

Tags: vb.net

Frist of all sorry for my bad english.

I'm making an application in VB.NET and I have a little problem.
I have two forms one main FORM (always open), and one that I open as Dialog.

In the secondary form (such as the open dialog) I can choose what to do and based on what I choose I have to trigger an event in the main form.
Let me explain, In the child form I choose the customer number 2, I press OK, and the main form has to load all the data related to the customer number 2.

Obviously, being object-oriented vb.net I can not call a sub from another form (because I do not have access to the instance) and I can not declare a new one, because the main form is always open.

How do I then pass the id of the customer and raise the event to load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expose the customer ID in the child through a Public or Friend property, for example (child form):

```
Public Property CustomerID as Integer

Private Sub OK_Click(s as Object, e as eventargs) Handles OK.Click
    CustomerID = id 'pass the value here
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok
End Sub
```

On the main form then:

```
If frmChild.ShowDialog = DialogResult.Ok Then
    MessageBox.Show("Customer ID: " + frmChild.CustomerID)
End If
```

Comment: Don't forget the "Dim frmchild as new myOtherForm"... I can imagine it being very annoying if you didn't know that from the start as a beginner with passing data between forms.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a weirdo! I know that the data is passed through properties and in theory I was also aware of the fact that I could use the DialogBox but as I write the code, I always wonder if that's the proper way, I always miss something.
Thank you for your help now everything works!