# Passing the data between windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a windows application.
In which I want to call one form from another and take Yes/No option from user
and that Yes/No choice again passed to the parent form.

How to do this ? 
I have tried by creating object but it dont work. 
[image]

Please check below image... 
I have Call conformation form on click of final button, when user choose ok/Cancel that value passed to the again parent form and will take desired action depends on choice. 
how to take input from this child form ?

Comment: are you talking about displaying a dialog and maybe getting something back like maybe a dialog result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET Pass Data Between Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938530/vb-net-pass-data-between-forms)

Comment: These questions come up about once a week (on a good week) here on SO. The answer is always the same (including the bad answers, like xpda's below). The questions, in fact, are nearly always the same. Why are we so cursed?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to set a variable to Public when you instantiate it.

```
 Public myVariable as String = ""
```

Then you would access it from anywhere.

- From your own form

  ```
  Me.myVariable = "" 'Whatever you would like to set
  ```
- From another Form

  ```
  Form1.myVariable = "" 'Whatever you would like to set
  'or
  FormName.Variable = ""
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim confirmModal = new ConfirmModal 
 Dim result = confirmModal.ShowDialog()
 If result = OK then resltValue = confirmModal.ResultValue
```

ResultValue is whatever you want to pass to the parent.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a public variable in a module or in the parent form that is accessed by both forms to store the yes/no value.

```
public returnCode as boolean
```

If the variable is in the parent form, it can be referenced in the child form using the parent form's name:

```
form1.returnCode = True
```