# VB.NET Pass Data Between Forms. How to catch the result of Dialogresult.Ok

Tags: vb.net, forms, dialog, showdialog

I am trying to return some data from a subform I open with showdialog

I referred to this question on stack overflow: [VB.NET Pass Data Between Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938530/vb-net-pass-data-between-forms)

Here is the code. I know the code you write on the subform:

```
Public Property CustomerID as Integer

Private Sub OK_Click(s as Object, e as eventargs) Handles OK.Click
    CustomerID = id 'pass the value here
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok
End Sub
```

But I dont know where to enter the code that goes in the main form

```
If frmChild.ShowDialog = DialogResult.Ok Then
    MessageBox.Show("Customer ID: " + frmChild.CustomerID)
End If
```

I cant just paste this code anywhere. Do I make a Public sub to paste this code or is there another way. I just want to start reading data from subform as soon as dialog result gets ok

Comment: You don't need `Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok` in code, you can set this in designer for every button in your dialog form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to display your sub form.  Do you want to display it as a result of a button click?  If so, you could put your code into the button click event handler:

```
Private Sub _showSubFormButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles _showSubFormButton.Click
    Dim frmChild = New SubForm

    If frmChild.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        MessageBox.Show("Customer ID: " & frmChild.CustomerID)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to display as soon as user presses ok in the SubForm
And I was hoping if there was a way to do it without using too many Public strings

Comment: No, I mean how is the SubForm itself displayed?

Comment: I.e. what causes it to be displayed?  Does it get displayed when the user clicks a button on the main form?

Comment: Subform is dplayed when user presses button on main form

Comment: Then put your code into that button's event handler.

Comment: So After I write Subform1.ShowDialog(), I paste the bit of code on the bottom?